# javascript delete files on the server by ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to delete files on the **SERVER** by javascript, and I already read the tips from 
[delete files by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721621/how-to-delete-file-from-folder-using-javascript)

My part of javascript is current looks like that,

```
deleteFile = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "delete.php"
  }).success(function(responce) {
    if (responce === 'deleted') {
      return alert("deleted");
    }
  });
};
```

And my "delete.php" is looks like that

```
<?php
  if unlink("data/hello.json")
     print "deleted"
?>
```

And I am using commend  **python3 -m http.server 8000** to setup server.

When I perform deletion, which run the function deleteFile(), and I got the following message in terminal, 
**localhost - - [01/Dec/2015 17:19:17 "GET /delete.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -**

That means the "delete.php" can be "GET" correctly, right? However, "data/hello.json" still exist, that means "delete.php" did not execute. I also check if "delete.php" is executable by using commend php -f delete.php , and it works, "data/hello.json" is deleted ! That means there should be no problem with my php script.

I am wondering where I went wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Try the php like '<?php   if (unlink("data/hello.json"))     print "deleted"; ?>' and execute it directly and see if it is working anyway.

Comment: Have you try absolute path to the file "data/hello.json"? And did you get this alert after AJAX call: return alert("deleted"); Also not sure if print "deleted" is good.

Comment: I tried <?php if (unlink("data/hello.json")) print "deleted"; ?> , it works when I manually use commend  "php -f delete.php" , but it does not work with ajax "GET" request from the javascript, even though I got the message "localhost - - [03/Dec/2015 10:19:17 "GET /delete.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -"

Answer (score 0):

This file could be accessed by some process and on Linux systems will be deleted when process closes this file.

In addition to that. You should not be using HTTP `GET` method for anything which changes data state. You can use `POST` or `DELETE` methods instead.

Also I don't see any user authorisation being done. Do you indend anyone to be able to delete you files?

Comment: "POST" request may work, but the python server does not support "POST" request, might use other servers to do so.          Since everything is in my local machine, everyone using this machine is able to delete the files.